# using arraylist to save strings from servlet and retrieve the same arraylist in other servlet to retrieve data

Tags: java, servlets, arraylist

Hello Guys i am new with java, I am trying to save form data into an array list through a servlet sent through html and using second servlet to retrieve the same arraylist. 
The problem is, i can add the data into list using servlet one using "is.setAl(str);" as well retrieve data in servlet one. but when i try to retrieve data in servlet 2 using "arrList = is.getAl();" it gives null value.

below are my Servlets and object code.

---

Servlet 1:

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static InfoSave is = new InfoSave();
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doPost(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BufferedReader br =request.getReader();

    String str = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("The String Recieved is:\n"+str);

    is.setAl(str);  


    System.out.println("----> "+is.getAl()+"\n");

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().write(str);
}
```

---

Servlet 2:

```
public class SearchServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static InfoSave is = new InfoSave();
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doPost(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BufferedReader br = request.getReader();

    String str = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(str);


     ArrayList<String> arrList = null, result = null;

      arrList = is.getAl();
      System.out.println("\n"+arrList);
      result = new ArrayList<>();
      for (Iterator iterator = arrList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
      {
        String string = (String) iterator.next();
        if(string.contains(str)){
            result.add(string);
        }else{
            String message = "No Matching result Found";
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.getWriter().write(str);
        }

      }
      System.out.println("Size: "+result.size());
      String json = new Gson().toJson(result);


    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
}
}
```

---

ArrayList Object:

```
public class InfoSave {
private ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<String> getAl() {
    return al;
}

public void setAl(String s) {
    al.add(s);
}
}
```

Comment: you need to create object of InfoSave to acess its method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In servlet 2 you are accessing the static variable `is` of servlet 2, and not the `is` variable of servlet 1; they don't reference the same `InfoSave` object. The variable from servlet 2 is not populated and when you call `is.getAl()` the returned list is empty.

In this case, if you want to share information across this two servlets you can put the object in the session in servlet 1 and retrieve from session in servlet 2.

Servlet 1:

```
...
InfoSave is = new InfoSave();
is.setAl(str);
request.getSession().setAttribute("IS", is);
...
```

Servlet 2:

```
...
InfoSave is = (InfoSave) request.getSession().getAttribute("IS");
arrList = is.getAl();
...
```

In this way you don't need to use the static variables in the servlets.

For more information about servlet sessions:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-session-tracking.htm

Answer (score 0):

In Servlet 2:

`arrList = is.getAl();`  change to `TestServlet.is.getAl();`

`is` in Servlet 2 and Servlet 1 are different object.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, *do not even try to do that!*

Servlet are intended to be called from a servlet container for different client sessions in a possibly multi-threaded way. That means that they should be stateless objects. You could use a publicly accessible static `InfoSave` object in one servlet and use it from the other, but that would not be the *Java EE way*.

The correct way if to use a session attribute if you want one InfoSave per active session, or in a servlet context one, if you want one single shared list. The advantage of doing so is that you can more easily switch from on way to the other.

Here an example code using the session:

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ...    
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Get access to a session scoped InfoSave - local to keep the servlet stateless
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        InfoSave is = (InfoSave) session.getAttribute("INFOSAVE");
        if (is == null) { // no InfoSave here: create a brand new one
            is = new InfoSave();
            session.setAttribute("INFOSAVE", is); // store it into the session
        }
        // the remaining of the code can safely access the session scoped InfoSave
        ...
    }
}
```

BTW, it you wanted to use a static InfoSave or store it in a servlet context attribute, you should synchronize the accesses because more than one thread can execute a servlet at the same time - but hopefully only one can use a given session...